". . . the smile splitting her face"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 17)

(William's mother Evelyn is visiting her son, a chorister probationer, for the first time. They are having lunch in a restaurant)


He (William) tells her - even though she already knows - that because Martin was sick, he (William) sang a solo and did so well that Phillip (the choirmaster) wanted him in the choir by half-term, helped by Porter's voice breaking.
'So from next week, I'll be sitting with the choristers, next to Martin.'
Evelyn has picked up her cutlery and is struggling to chew her food because of the smile splitting her face. William wants to keep her happy.

Are the bold words idiomatic language? I know split one's sides laughing but I don't know the wording in hand.

I would have thought "her face split into a smile" is a reasonably common way of saying "she smiled". Your quotation develops a consequence of that.

The "splitting her face" phrasing is a one-off, which is contextually licensed because she's trying to chew her food without opening her mouth (observing the standard injunction "Don't chew with your mouth open"). You wouldn't use that "split" metaphor normally in conversation, but her face split into a wide grin is a literary cliche, and we might say a smile broke out on her face.

It's just using the language poetically. A scream split the night's tranquility.

"Idiomatic" has two meanings - one relates to something being an idiom, the other means something that sounds like a native speaker (see the did you know? section).

@FumbleFingers What a disturbingly macabre collocation! Historically the only smile that ever split anyone's face was Lizzie Borden's, faces not her own. For whatever reason, I've never read this until here and now; perhaps it’s due to my—ahem, “antemilllennial”—English education in which such grotesque collocations did not (yet?) occur. I recommend more investigation into the more historically typical collocations here via COCA and the BNC.

Since the year 2000 this expression is found often in the literature; this is shown in the ngrams below; it has to be considered idiomatic.

smile splitting her face (159 occurrences)

smile splitting his face (156 occurrences)
The forms shown in the two ngrams above are the -ing clauses that correspond to the the finite forms

"a smile/grin split < someone's > face".

The ngram below  shows that the finite form  with the pronoun "her"  is used just as much.

a smile split her face (128 occurrences)
Strangely enough, "the smile/grin splitting his face" is found frequently, but not a single corresponding form with "her" can be found for either "smile" or "grin". This is shown  in the two  ngrams that follow. (I wouldn't take this sort of anomaly as a sign that the expressions with "the" might be non-idiomatic; there must be another explanation.)

the smile splitting his face (41 occurrences)

the grin splitting his face (73 occurrences)


Without comparing the phrase to similar expressions it's too early in the day to say that "smile/grin split ... is an idiom. If it were, it would be listed in dictionaries. Is it? Note that "grin" with "splitting" is more common than "smile".

"face split into" [a grin]

@Mari-LouA No, I haven't found it in dictionaries, as otherwise, in most cases, I quote a dictionary definition; yet, the number of occurrences that Google Books finds make it inescapable to conclude that it is an idiom. It is true that I haven't provided the links to the pages of research (I might do that later), but if you check those pages you're bound to conclude it is an expression that is familiar to a lot of people.

I'm not sure that the vertical scale on those graphs can be taken as evidence of idiomaticity. (That is, I'm rather sure it can't.)

@AndrewLeach The occurrences of this form are numerous; I just added the links and an ngram showing possible modifiers.

There is evidence only of the formulaic nature of the phrase.  It is not ungrammatical, It is not an idiom.  It is a "stock" description.  What does it mean? That half of her face is smiling?  Some people think it describes the transition from non-smile to smile. Some people think it's a half smile, a not fully committed smile. Who knows? ;-z

@TimR We can be sure there is nothing new  in matters of smiling; this expression is used a lot in connection with smiles that are said to be huge, broad, wide ,  big,—shown in one of the the ngrams—, hardly half smiles… I believe that there is not all that mystery about this image; it is merely a way to communicate vividly the fact that an appreciable distortion of  the features has occured, and it is not an expression that I would use for the Mona Lisa.

That it’s idiomatic does not make it an idiom. As for the image, think Julia Roberts.  Just a wide smile by a generous mouth.

@Xanne Let's take "idiom" as meaning "group of words whose meaning is different from the meaning of the individual words (OALD)", which is what is "smile split someone's face", and "idiomatic" as "containing an idiom: an idiomatic expression (OALD"). Moreover, it is also "idiomatic" in the sense of "containing expressions that are natural to a native speaker of the language (OALD)" (meaning in answer); several hundred hits in a respectable enough literature points irremediably to the truth of this fact. // There seems to be no problem with "wide smile", (1/2)

@Xanne  where "wide" is meant to say "measuring a lot from one side to the other (a wide grin) (OALD)". Perhaps "generous mouth"  would be "plain" language if  "generous" was taken  as  "rich and full",  for instance when used with "wine", in "generous wine" (SOED), but I don't really know: can you  speak of a "rich" mouth?  (2/2)

@lph I don’t think it’s an idiom.  It’s a straightforward use of words to describe something.  It’s not great writing, but it is understandable from the literal meaning of the words.

@Xanne Understandable, yes, but from an enlightened reader's point of view, a reader used to draw automatically upon an aqcuired stock of analogies; otherwise, there is no literal splitting. The meanings of "split" do not yield an explanation; therefore, there is no other way: even expressions such as "to split the difference" or  "to split  an infinitive" and "split hairs", which are also understandable, are idioms. What then about "split your sides with laughter", which is also a recorded  idiom (OALD)?

@LPH  No, not every metaphorical or symbolic use of a word results in an idiom—an expression that must be learned on its own rather than understood from the meaning of the individual words. Native speakers would understand “splitting hairs”; what learners need is not more idioms to learn, but more understanding of the use of vocabulary in metaphors and analogies.

The understanding of vocabulary is greatly enhanced by reading rather than memorizing lists of words or so-called idioms.
